# how to make responsive dialog in angular

Tags: html, css, angular, dialog, styles

CSS is not my thing and I'm trying to make my mat dialog to be responsive on any screen size so I would be really appreciate if I can get any suggestion or help on how to fix this.

When I switch to bigger screen size, the dialog container got bigger but the two columns size remain the same. I tried to do percentage instead of px for the height but some reason the two columns size become even smaller.

Also when the browser get smaller and smaller, I can see the horizontal scroll bar and the close bottom disappear.

```
<div mat-dialog-content class="dialog-container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="column left" style="background-color:#aaa;">
          <h2>Column 1</h2>
          <p>Some text..</p>
        </div>
        <div class="column right" style="background-color:#bbb;">
          <h2>Column 2</h2>
          <p>Some text..</p>
        </div>
      </div>

    <div mat-dialog-actions class="button">
        <button mat-raised-button color="primary" mat-dialog-close style="margin-left:100px;">Close</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
.dialog-container{
    width: 1100px;
    height:1000px;
    padding: 10px;
    overflow: 0;
    border-radius: 4px;
    outline: 0;
    overflow-y: hidden !important;
    overflow-x: hidden !important;
}   
.button{
    margin-top: 15px;
    align-items: left;
    margin-left: 900px;

}
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }
  
  .column {
    float: left;
    padding: 10px;
  }

  .left {
    width: 25%;
    position: relative;
    height: 400px;
  }
  
  .right {
    position: relative;
    width: 75%;
    height: 400px;
  }
  
  /* Clear floats after the columns */
  .row:after {
    position: relative;
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
  }
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using CSS media rule. It would help you to apply different styles for different media types/devices.

Media queries can be used to check many things, such as:

1. width and height of the viewport
2. width and height of the device
3. orientation (is the tablet/phone in landscape or portrait mode?)
4. resolution

[CSS Media Query](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp)

For Example:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav a {
    float: none;
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to set your dialog dimensions as viewport units (vw and vh), and then inside dialog set container that has 100% height and 100% width (and maybe some padding).

Example

```
.dialog-container {
  width: 80vw;
  height: 80vh;
}

.container-inside-dialog {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 20px;
 }
```

And the start of your HTML

```
<div mat-dialog-content class="dialog-container">
    <div class="container-inside-dialog">
       ...
     </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Hi by any chance do you know why my buttom remain in the same position even when I make the browser screen size smaller. when I make the screen size smaller the button disappear instead of squishing into the columns.

Comment: Could you upload your code on stackblitz? It will be easier to help you.